# How can I get local resources in a controller in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, localization

I know I can use the namespace Resources to get resources within App_GlobalResources but how do I get local resources within a controller?

Example, a folder in Views folder called Misc, with a page.aspx, and a App_LocalResources folder with the file page.aspx.ascx.

Comment: Attaching a particular view to the controller fill defeat the purpose of MVC

Comment: I fail to see the relevance in your comment?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do is: `HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject("~/Views/FOLDER/VIEW.cshtml", "KEY").ToString();`